# How to extract the table for each subject from the URL link in R - Webscraping

Tags: html, r, url, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the table for each subject:

This is the main link `https://htmlaccess.louisville.edu/classSchedule/setupSearchClassSchedule.cfm?error=0` It looks like below:

[image]

I have to select each subject and click search, which takes to the link `https://htmlaccess.louisville.edu/classSchedule/searchClassSchedule.cfm`

Each subject gives a different table. For subject `Accounting` I tried to get the table like below: I used `Selector Gadget` Chrome extension to get the `node string` for `html_nodes`

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

url <- "https://htmlaccess.louisville.edu/classSchedule/searchClassSchedule.cfm"
df <- read_html(url) 

tot <- df %>%
  html_nodes('table+ table td') %>%
  html_text()
```

But it didn't work:

```
## show
tot
character(0)
```

Is there a way to get the tables for each subject in a code with R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the site requires a web form be submitted - that's what happens when you click the "Search" button on the page. Without submitting that form, you won't be able to access the data. This is evident if you attempt to navigate to the link you're trying to scrape - punch that into your favorite web browser and you'll see that there's no tables at all at "https://htmlaccess.louisville.edu/classSchedule/searchClassSchedule.cfm". No wonder nothing shows up!

Fortunately, you *can* submit web forms with R. It requires a little bit more code, however. My favorite package for this is `httr`, which partners nicely with `rvest`. Here's the code that will submit a form using `httr` and then proceed with the rest of your code.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)

request_body <- list(
  term="4212",
  subject="ACCT", 
  catalognbr="",
  session="none",
  genEdCat="none",
  writingReq="none",
  comBaseCat="none",
  sustainCat="none",
  starttimedir="0",
  starttimehour="08",
  startTimeMinute="00",
  endTimeDir="0",
  endTimeHour="22",
  endTimeMinute="00",
  location="any",
  classstatus="0",
  Search="Search"
)

resp <- httr::POST(
  url = paste0("https://htmlaccess.louisville.edu/class",
               "Schedule/searchClassSchedule.cfm"), 
  encode = "form", 
  body = request_body)
httr::status_code(resp)
df <- httr::content(resp)

tot <- df %>%
  html_nodes("table+ table td") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  matrix(ncol=17, byrow=TRUE)
```

On my machine, that returns a nicely formatted matrix with the expected data. Now, the challenge was figuring out what the heck to put in the request body. For this, I use Chrome's "inspect" tool (right click on a webpage, hit "inspect"). On the "Network" tab of that side panel, you can track what information is being sent by your browser. If I start on the main page and keep that side tab up while I "search" for accounting, I see that the top hit is "searchClassSchedule.cfm" and open that up by clicking on it. There, you can see all the form fields that were submitted to the server and I simply copied those over into R manually.

Your job will be to figure out what shortened name the rest of the departments use! "ACCT" seems to be the one for "Accounting". Once you've got those names in a vector you can loop over them with a `for` loop or `lapply` statement:

```
dept_abbrevs <- c("ACCT", "AIRS")
lapply(dept_abbrevs, function(abbrev){
  ...code from above...
  ...after defining message body...
  message_body$subject <- abbrev
  ...rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: @Dubukey Thanks a lot. this is very helpful. But Is there a way to get the tables of each subject with one code? Is it possible to use multiple subjects for `subject` in `request_body`?

Comment: OR can I read subjects into a variable `all_subj <- c("ACCT", "AIRS", "ASL")`  and run the code with `for loop`? Is it possible? If it is possible could you please show me an example? thanq

Comment: @beginner I've edited my answer to reflect your additional request for help! If that explains it, feel free to hit the green "check" so we know you're happy with the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry I couldn't understand the above `lapply` code. Could you please post the whole code? I'm having some mistakes.